# Angularjs Firebase doesnt work with IE and android browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, internet-explorer

My app works fine with Google Chrome (in android too), however when i try to open it throw IE or android browser, angular code crashes.

Who knows what is the reason for that??

Thanks in advance!

It get stuck at this line

```
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Categories/');
  dbRef.once('value', snap => {

    snap.forEach(function(childSnap) {

      $scope.allcats.push(childSnap.val());
      $scope.$apply();
    })
```

and following this:

[image of in the console](https://ibb.co/e1LcJ6)

Here is error shown in the console
     SCRIPT5022: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=app1&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.6%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dapp1%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A26%3A402)%0A%20%20%20at%20b%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A25%3A420)%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A26%3A175)%0A%20%20%20at%20Anonymous%20function%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A288)%0A%20%20%20at%20p%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A5)%0A%20%20%20at%20g%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A138)%0A%20%20%20at%20hb%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A46%3A244)%0A%20%20%20at%20c%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A17)%0A%20%20%20at%20Uc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A325)%0A%2

Comment: When it work in Chrome and doesnt work in IE, maybe there's some code that doesn't support in IE. That error message shows links to angular that has message `Failed to instantiate module app1 due to:` . Maybe you can show some of your code for suspect in creating this error.

Comment: @egon12 please check. i updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer doesnt support arrow function, so try to change

```
dbRef.once('value', snap => {
```

to

```
dbRef.once('value', function(snap) {
```

update:

Also there something that you must change. When you use arrow function, `this` will refer to what you ussualy think to (ex: the Class, the Controller or something). But when you use unnamed function `this` keyword will refer to the function itself.

ex:

```
this.b = 1
a.onChange( e => {
    console.log(this.b) // works
}
```

but this won't work

```
this.b = 1
a.onChange( function(e) {
    console.log(this.b) // will be undefined
}
```

to solve this problem you need to create variable that refer to this.

ex:

```
this.b = 1
var self = this
a.onChange( function(e) {
    console.log(self.b)
}
```

Comment: yes, it doesnt give previous errors, however new error is occured SCRIPT5007: Failed to get the "updateSnapshot" property of a reference whose value is not defined or is NULL       in firebase.js

Comment: thanks, however what is the use if that in my function?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not read the comment carefully, who created firebase.js file?, and did you created "updateSnapshot" function/variable?